# Regex - Select First Match from Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, php, regex, parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the url of a javascript code.
Everything was fine until I noticed that this code randomly shows 3 or more url within the same line, so the PHP function I was using no longer worked for me.

So I am trying to select from the following code only the first URL but I am not good with the regex (its in one line):

```
"https:\/\/sample.domain.com\/201706\/26\/13912879\/720p_1500k_13912879\/sample_video_name.mp4?rate=190k&burst=1200k&validfrom=1499826300&validto=1499840700&hash=%2BDsIFr8fnCAx2cz%2BAgsQEY9jjb4%3D"},{"defaultQuality":false,"format":"","quality":"480","videoUrl":"https:\/\/sample.domain.com\/201706\/26\/13912879\/480p_750k_13912879\/sample_video_name_2.mp4?rate=108k&burst=1200k&validfrom=1499826300&validto=1499840700&hash=8rL1ttX15bHmwFKINHUUewnEv8A%3D"},{"defaultQuality":false,"format":"","quality":"240","videoUrl":"https:\/\/sample.domain.com\/201706\/26\/13912879\/240p_240k_13912879\/sample_video_name_3.mp4?rate=59k&burst=1200k&validfrom=1499826300&validto=1499840700&hash=Frj6AcBMp8zrHKttan%2BDYEmktTY%3D"
```

I tried to use the following code but this one selects me all the url, I just want the first one:

```
https:([^"]+)
```

Example with regexr:
http://regexr.com/3gb4u

Comment: use the /https:([^"]+)/i instance of  /https:([^"]+)/g (http://regexr.com/3gb54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, you can remove the global flag to only match the first instance.  Depending on how you've implemented your regex in php or javascript, you may need to determine how to disable the global setting in that specific regex attempt.

http://regexr.com/3gb51